# Error processing block: Catalog.block.InitializeItemIndexingView, System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sitecore-commerce, coveo

I'm trying to set up a commerce project on my local environment. I've created a new organization in Coveo, I made the necesary config changes, and for some reason, the products are not being shown in search results (only the articles).

I've rebuilt the solr and sitecore indexes in Sitecore, I did `Refresh Commerce Cache` in Content Editor, and nothing makes the product appear in the search result.

I've found the below error in CommerceMinions log files, but I didn't find any help on the internet.

```
00014 13:33:12 ERROR Pipeline completed with error
System.Exception: Error processing block: Catalog.block.InitializeItemIndexingView ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.InitializeItemIndexingViewBlock.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.ReflectionPipelineBlockRunner.<InvokeBlock>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.BasePipelineBlockRunner.<Run>d__3`1.MoveNext()
00052 13:38:58 WARN CtxMsg.Warning.MinionProcessingSameEntities: Text=Minion 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.DeleteIndexDocumentsMinion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search' didn't run. There is a minion processing the same type of entities in the 'Client_Name_Minions' environment running.
00042 13:39:14 ERROR ItemIncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Item Indexing failed on prepare. Index Client_Name_master_index does not exists.
00042 13:39:14 ERROR ItemIncrementalIndexMinion-Incremental Item Indexing failed on prepare. Index Client_Name_web_index does not exists.
```